# Ng-Select Options Value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to create an ng-select to select your country and pass through the associated country code. I have a hash, but I'm not sure if its correct.

```
<select ng-model="myCountry" ng-options="country.name group by country.iso for country     in countries" placeholder="Country">


</select>
```

```
$scope.countries= [{name: 'Canada', iso: 'CA'}, {name: 'United States', iso: 'US'}];
```

How do I get the 'iso' to pass as a value with the 'name', also I can't seem to get it to default at a placeholder of country.

Please let me know if I'm not clear enough

Comment: I missed the placeholder requirement before... I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 <select ng-model="myCountry" ng-options="country.iso as country.name group by country.iso for country     in countries" placeholder="Country">
       <option value="">Country</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want this syntax for your expression:

```
<select ng-model="myCountry" ng-options="country.iso as country.name for country in countries" placeholder="Country">
  <option style="display:none" value="">Country</option>
</select>
```

Given that your `group by` appears to be unique per item, I'm guessing you don't really want that as a `select` grouping